# PCA9685 detected on Command Line, but not by Python

Tags: servo, adafruit, circuitpython

I'm trying to hook up a SC90 servo to my Pi3 B using a PCA9685. I think I have it connected correctly, because I get correct `i2cdetect` results.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: 40 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

However, when I try to run Adafruit's sample code:

```py
from board import SCL, SDA
import busio
from adafruit_pca9685 import PCA9685

i2c_bus = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)
pca = PCA9685(i2c_bus)

pca.frequency = 60
pca.channels[0].duty_cycle = 0x7FFF
```

I get the following error on the line `pca = ...`

```py
>>> %Run servo-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 174, in __probe_for_device
    self.i2c.writeto(self.device_address, b"")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/busio.py", line 169, in writeto
    return self._i2c.writeto(address, buffer, stop=stop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 52, in writeto
    self._i2c_bus.write_bytes(address, buffer[start:end])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 314, in write_bytes
    self._device.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 180, in __probe_for_device
    self.i2c.readfrom_into(self.device_address, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/busio.py", line 159, in readfrom_into
    return self._i2c.readfrom_into(address, buffer, stop=stop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 59, in readfrom_into
    readin = self._i2c_bus.read_bytes(address, end - start)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 181, in read_bytes
    return self._device.read(number)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/servo-test.py", line 17, in <module>
    pca = PCA9685(i2c)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_pca9685.py", line 141, in __init__
    self.i2c_device = i2c_device.I2CDevice(i2c_bus, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.__probe_for_device()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 183, in __probe_for_device
    raise ValueError("No I2C device at address: 0x%x" % self.device_address)
ValueError: No I2C device at address: 0x40
```

I'm confused by the `ValueError`, because I detected it fine.

Comment: Try running http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_PCA9685_py It needs the pigpio daemon (`sudo pigpiod`),

Comment: The error you should be concentrating on is `OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error` rather than anything else.

Comment: @Dougie doesn't that stem from the ValueError? (Either way, do you have any comments other than "you're asking the wrong question"?)

Comment: @Milliways How about a suggestion?

Comment: @joan I get an error
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/PCA9685.py", line 163, in <module>
    pwm = PCA9685.PWM(pi) # defaults to bus 1, address 0x40
  File "/home/pi/Downloads/PCA9685.py", line 66, in __init__
    self._write_reg(self._MODE1, self._AI | self._ALLCALL)
...
pigpio.error: 'I2C write failed'
```

Comment: I do not know why you get that error.  It should work as long as the default bus (i2c1)  and device address (0x40) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong library. I have a Sunfounder PCA9685, but I was using the Adafruit library, assuming it was the same. The Sunfounder library works perfectly.